# Composer - Mapping the src directory to the document root with the vendor folder outside

Tags: php, composer-php, restler

I have the following folder structure.

```
src/
  |- index.php
test/
vendor/
composer.json
composer.lock
```

When i want to deploy my code, I realize that i have to map the src/ directory to document root since it contains the index.php file (which btw contains some Restler code)
However, if i do that, how do i deal with the vendor/ folder that lies outside the document root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vendor folder **MUST** be outside of the web root for better security

When you include `autoload.php` or `restler.php`, it will take care of making those classes (residing in vendor folder) available

Ideally you should keep your index.php in a folder named `public` and use `src` folder for keeping your own code