# Composer web application folder structure

Tags: php, url, url-routing, composer-php

I am working on an application that would exist in a sub directory on a web root. My application folder structure is:

```
website root/           
  |- index.php
  |- my-application/
       |- src/
           |- index.php
       |- tests/
       |- vendor/
       |- .gitignore
       |- composer.json
       |- phpunit.xml
```

According to this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24073451/2762145), the src directory should be in the root directory.  This is not possible in this situation.

In addition to this when installing this application, the index for the application is now within the src folder in the application folder.  This means the url would be localhost/application/src/index.php.

What can i do to make the url for the application index file, localhost/application/index.php?

I have no control over the webroot.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about web administration and as such better fits to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your source file layout should always include a "src" (or "lib" or whatever you want to call it) folder which contains all the necessary source code, likely a "vendor" folder which contains 3rd party code, and a "webroot" folder which is the only folder in this setup which will be publicly exposed via a web server. E.g.:

```
myapp/
    src/
        Acme/
            MyApp/
                ...
    vendor/
        ...
    webroot/
        index.php
        css/
            ...
        js/
            ...
```

You can store this folder anywhere you like. In the end you configure the web server to serve `myapp/webroot/`. You can do this by:

1. symlinking that folder into the web server's document root:

   ```
   /var/www/myapp -> /usr/local/myapp/webroot
   ```
2. using mod_rewrite directives to rewrite requests accordingly:

   ```
   RewriteRule /theapp/(.*) /usr/local/myapp/webroot/$1
   ```
3. configuring the web server's core accordingly to serve certain URLs from your app's directory:

   ```
   Alias /theapp /usr/local/myapp/webroot
   # or whatever other way you prefer
   ```

You are not required in any way to store files in the filesystem exactly as the URLs will appear. It's the web server's job to handle this resolution between URLs and files and/or programmatic responses, and it offers many tools to make this as flexible as necessary. Use those tools.

Comment: I agree with everything you are saying here, but it doesn't make sense with my use case of an application some customer would be extracting to a folder and running.  I wouldn't have access to the webserver.

Comment: Then your customer should be setting it up accordingly. If the only thing that's possible is to drop a folder into another folder (mostly because the "admin" in this case cannot do any of the other things), then there's little you can do. You can use .htaccess files to rewrite the URL as you like.